# How do I switch out what a symbolic link directory is pointing to from Lua

Tags: lua, symlink

I am using this UI developer called Crank Software: http://www.cranksoftware.com/ which provides an API for lua.  I'm trying to have a user interface that has multiple versions of the images with the images folder being a symbolic link and have some outside action trigger my lua code to switch which directory the symbolic link is pointing to.  For instance: /big/imagea.png, /small/imagea.png, /medium/imagea.png

I haven't used Symbolic Links before and I am newish to lua as well, so kindly break it down into smallish steps if you would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua did not provide any lib to handle the filesystem, if you want to know the directory is symbolic or not, you have to use a exported function from the native code (e.g. the Crank software) or write your own.

I don't know which platform you are working on, so can't help you to write this function.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks.  I'll write the code, but at least this way I won't be barking up the wrong tree.  Platform may change anyway. :/